# use Variable as methods in PHP chain to allow conditional method chaining

Tags: php, function, methods, method-chaining

Is there a way to build the chain conditionally? Example:

```
$chain = $restaurant->allFoods()->$filter->get();
```

Then `$filter` is dynamic or conditionally set

```
if ($user == "vegetarian")
{
    $filter = "->onlyVegetables()";
}
```

So if condition is met, the chain would become:

```
$chain = $restaurant->allFoods()->onlyVegetables()->get();
```

else

```
$chain = $restaurant->allFoods()->get();
```

Is this possible? What is this called? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: Building dynamical code is possible with eval, but most say: "eval is evil"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, through overloading with methods __get/__call, depending on if you need to pass arguments to the filter or not.

```
<?php
function __get($user) {
  if($user == 'vegetarian') {
    return $this->onlyVegetables();
  }
  return $this;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Comment: what if I cannot append `__get()` nor `__call()` to the parent Model?

Comment: You can either extend the class or write a wrapper to implement facade methods for filters. It depends on the class(es) you are trying to use.